# Combine Java string arrays into one object

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hi I have these three static objects that I would like to combine programmatically. For example:

```
private static final String[] DESEASE = new String[] {
    "Alcoholism", "Animal Desease", "Brain Desease", "Demantia", "Movement Disorder"
};

private static final String[] GENE = new String[] {
    "A1CF", "A2LD1", "A2M", "AA06", "AA1"
};

private static final String[] GEO = new String[] {
    "GSE14429", "GSE4226", "GSE8632", "GS9134", "GSE8641"
};
```

I do not want to iterate. Want to do something of the type:

```
String[] resultList = DESEASE resultList.addAll(GENE).addAll(GEO);
```

Comment: What would you like the `String`s in `resultList` to look like?  Do you want `resultList` to be a 15-element array with all the strings, or do you want a 5-element array with the corresponding strings combined in some way?

Comment: resultList will go as a String Array as parm to another method, but can be converted in between.

Comment: No Just the 15 elements in a single array

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list,DESEASE);
    Collections.addAll(list,GENE);
    Collections.addAll(list,GEO);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a really neat way to do that. This will work, without using third-party libraries, though not exactly pretty:

```
private static final String[] resultList;
static {
    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(DESEASE));
    tmpList.addAll(Arrays.asList(GENE));
    tmpList.addAll(Arrays.asList(GEO));
    resultList = tmpList.toArray(new String[tmpList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `Collection`, which offers an almost literal version of the example you give:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.addAll(Arrays.asList(DESEASE));
data.addAll(Arrays.asList(GENE));
data.addAll(Arrays.asList(GEO));
String[] resultList = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
```

Which essentially creates a new Collection and adds everything to it before  converting it back to an array.

Or you could do it using new arrays, and the [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method:

```
String[] resultList = new String[DESEASE.length + GENE.length + GEO.length];
System.arraycopy(DESEASE, 0, resultList, 0, DESEASE.length);
System.arraycopy(GENE, 0, resultList, DESEASE.length, GENE.length);
System.arraycopy(GEO, 0, resultList, DESEASE.length + GENE.length, GEO.length);
```

Which creates a new array and copies each sub array into the required slots.

I haven't actually tested which is faster but System.arraycopy out-sources to a native method and doesn't have as much object creation so I would wager at that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions (Collections and `System.arraycopy()`):

Collections:

```
    List<String> allAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    allAsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(DESEASE));
    allAsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(GENE));
    allAsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(GEO));
    System.out.println(allAsList);
```

ArrayCopy:

```
    String[] allAsArray = new String[DESEASE.length + GENE.length + GEO.length];
    System.arraycopy(DESEASE, 0, allAsArray, 0, DESEASE.length);
    System.arraycopy(GENE, 0, allAsArray, DESEASE.length, GENE.length);
    System.arraycopy(GEO, 0, allAsArray, DESEASE.length + GENE.length, GEO.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(allAsArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectArrays.concat(T[],T[],Class<T>)` from Google Guava, and then use nested calls:

```java
import static com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.concat;
...
final String [] resultList = concat(DESEASE, concat(GENE, GEO, String.class), String.class);
```

However, lists are more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way :

```
public String[] combineArray (String[] ... strings) {
    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        tmpList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings[i]));
    return tmpList.toArray(new String[tmpList.size()]);
}
```

And you can pass as many arguments as you want :)